# Nuget package for Oracle Unmanaged Provider with Entity Framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

According to the latest documentation from Oracle (Data Provider for .Net developer's guide, 12c Release 1)

The Chapter "Installing Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver"
states that the entity framework provider for the unmanaged driver is available on NuGet http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT152

> ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver Entity Framework 6 and Code First functionality are available through a NuGet package. OUI and Xcopy installations include this package as well, but require post-install configuration steps. The NuGet package for ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver Entity Framework automates these post-install steps, except for the application-specific connection string settings.

I searched for Oracle's official profile on NuGet, and I only see 3 packages from them. https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Oracle

There are lots of other people who have NuGet packages for shipping the Oracle.DataAccess.dll, but aside from the fact that they aren't official, there's nothing about the Entity Framework driver for the Unmanaged client (and I'm fairly sure that's a pretty blatant breach of the OTN license agreement to redistribute the unmanaged dll's...)

So, I've probably answered my own question... but is there anything I'm missing? Using the wrong version of Visual Studio or something? (tried searching within VS2015 and also on NuGet.org)
Was there a NuGet package for this and now it's gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a documentation error (and thanks for bringing it to our attention!). As of this writing (2/9/2016) there's currently no official Oracle Unmanaged Nuget packages available. The Entity Framework package currently on Nuget is for the Managed Driver only.

To install and configure ODP.NET Unmanaged Driver and its Entity Framework library, please use either the Oracle Installer install, or the Xcopy install:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

(And if you are planning to use Entity Designer you should make sure to install the 32-bit "ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio")

Comment: Ha! You're welcome. We just opted to stay with using the Managed Providers. From looking around on this all day, it seems like Oracle is really pushing developers to use the Managed provider. (Especially with Entity framework) I was surprised that after installing the full unmanaged 32 bit client, the EF provider wasn't in there. That would be great for EF deployments using the unmanaged provider and the customer already has a full client on there.

Comment: The EF provider is included in the unmanaged ODAC and XCOPY install links I provided. Look in the ODP.NET subdirectories... it is located in an "EF" subdirectory.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I know the provider is in the ODAC package. I had already had that installed on my dev machine. What I meant was, it would be nice if the regular Oracle client had the EF dll, so that customers who already have the regular client don't have to download another client. Bigger organizations are anal about having too many clients installed, and as I said, we opted to stay with the managed providers :)

Comment: Well, if the EF DLL is not included in your client you have probably installed an older version of ODP.NET. In older versions, the required EF functionality was built into Oracle.DataAccess.dll and it's configuration. An additional DLL was not required. We split them out in more recent versions. There are ways to deal with multiple unmanaged ODP.NET's on the same server and many organizations do that. Oracle Homes provide isolation and we have now introduced the concept of a "local" installation. XCopy installs allow you to perform your own install and "bring your own client".