# Using unmanaged Oracle.DataAccess driver with MVC5 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

For reasons beyond my control I have a working MVC5 app with an API using Entity Framework 6 and the Oracle Managed Data Access driver, but I need to switch this to use the unmanaged Oracle driver.  I have Oracle Client v12.3 installed. I tried removing the managed Oracle .NET NuGet packages, referenced the unmanaged driver in the project, and changed all of the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess references to Oracle.DataAccess. The Oracle Client install seems okay because I have an older app that works and uses the unmanaged Oracle driver.  Both apps are connecting to the same database.

The MVC app compiles and runs however when it attempts to connect to the database I get the following error when it constructs the DbConnection:

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices,
>   Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework, Version 4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' registered in the application config
>   file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

Does the Oracle unmanaged driver support EF6 and if so what configuration am I missing to allow it to load the driver? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EF6 does support Oracle.DataAccess.  However, you can't do it via Nuget.  Look at the link below for some guidance for someone that's actually resolve it.

[Nuget package for Oracle Unmanaged Provider with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297774/nuget-package-for-oracle-unmanaged-provider-with-entity-framework/35303125#35303125)